# blur an image by imagemagick

Tags: iphone, imagemagick

m a newbie in imagemagick...nd i wanted to know how to use some simple basic activities on an image by using imagemagic...i've also downloaded test project of imagemagic..but facin some problem..

Comment: What problems are you having?  What are you trying to do, and what's not working?  Are you using the command line tools or are you interacting with it via one of its language bindings?  If that latter, which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the tag "iphone" on this question, which makes me think you're blurring your image on a web server and then pulling it down to an iPhone.

There's a library I recently discovered but haven't had the opportunity to use yet that does image manipulations right on the phone. See here: http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/